# Enviar correo desde Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic, angular, typescript, cordova

Estoy siguiendo [esta guia](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer/), y no consigo que me funcione.

He instalado el pluggin y he copiado el siguiente código en mi método:

```
public enviarCorreo() {
      let email = {
      app: 'gmail',
      to: 'aaaaaaaa@gmail.com',
      cc: 'ssss@dddddd.cc',
      subject: 'Hola',
      body: 'Que piensas?',
      isHtml: true
    };
    this.emailComposer.open(email)
}
```

Pero no me hace nada al pusar al "Enviar". Investigando la consola, me dice el siguiente mensaje:

> Ionic Native: tried calling EmailComposer.open, but Cordova is not
>   available. Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator and b)
>   include cordova.js in your index.html

En la instalación básica entiendo que ya me debería de crear el archivo `cordova.js` pero he buscado en todo el disco y no está.
He buscado código en la web de Cordova, pero tampoco encuentro nada.
¿Qué archivo me falta? ¿Hay alguna alternativa?

Comment: Hola, puedes agregar el error o el fragmento del error donde dice que no encuentra el módulo `cordova`

Comment: Que versión de Ionic estás usando?, además dime en que plataforma estás corriendo tu aplicación (Navegador, Android o IOS).

Comment: Version de ionic es 4.0.6 y ejecuto la aplicacion en el navegador de Firefox y en Android con la aplicacion DevApp.

Comment: Hola, acabo de complementar la respuesta, prueba lo que te adjunto y me haces saber si soluciona tu error.

Answer (score 2):

voy a darte un paso a paso, y ya tu miras que es lo que te has saltado.

Primero debemos de instalar el plugin o complemento respectivo de `cordova-plugin-email-composer`, lo hacemos con los respectivos comandos:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-email-composer
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/email-composer
```

Puedes ejecutar cada comando por separado o los puedes ejecutar en una sola linea de la siguiente manera:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-email-composer && $ npm install --save @ionic-native/email-composer
```

Como segundo paso debemos de agregar el `plugin` al módulo de tu aplicacion `import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer';`.

Como se debería de ver en `app.module.ts`:

> **Nota:** Solo agrega lo que te he mencionado, lo demas es una simple base.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
//Agregamos el componente:
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    //Además procedemos a agregarlo como un provider.
    EmailComposer,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Y como último paso debes de ejecutarlo en tu componente o en la vista donde quieras realizar dicha función:

```
//Importacion del plugin
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  //Lo adicionamos en el constructor de la clase
  //emailComposer puedes declararla como tu quieras, es una variable, pero debes de tener cuidado cuando la vayas a usar, porque debe de llamarse igual.
  constructor(private emailComposer: EmailComposer) { }


  enviarCorreo() {
    let email = {
      to: 'sssss@ssssss.com',
      cc: 'ssss@dddddd.cc',
      subject: 'Hola',
      body: 'Que piensas?',
      isHtml: true
    };

    this.emailComposer.open(email);
  }

}
```

Te adjunto documentación para que puedas ampliar tus conceptos sobre este plugin:
[Vídeo tutorial](https://youtu.be/N27NBB9TgLI), y un
[Tutorial](https://ionicacademy.com/emails-image-attachments-ionic/) sobre dicha funcionalidad para `ionic` ó ya la documentación desde [ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer/)

**Problemas con CORDOVA**

Breve descripción de lo que esto resuelve:

Los complementos nativos no funcionan con el servidor en vivo para los usuarios que usan `Cordova 8`. La ruta actual en la configuración es válida para versiones menores a `Cordova 8`. Sin embargo, si instalas `ionic` hoy, siguiendo las instrucciones en el sitio obtienes `Cordova 8` por defecto y por lo tanto el el servidor en vivo no puede encontrar `Cordova`. Todo lo que intentes hacer en cuanto a operaciones nativas `native operations` da como resultado el mensaje de error: `Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator (running in emulator)`

Esto se ha roto desde al menos este `11/26/2016` [Pregunta en StackOverflow English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815183/ionic-2-cordova-is-not-available-make-sure-to-include-cordova-js-or-run-in-a-d).

Para mantener la compatibilidad con versiones anteriores de Cordova 7, modifica las variables de la ruta de la plataforma a las matrices de cadenas e incluí las posibles rutas de la plataforma.

Como solución, puedes editar el archivo:

> node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/dev-server/serve-config.js
>   reemplazar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual contiene esta sección de código JavaScript:

```
exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATH = path.join('platforms', 'android', 'assets', 'www');
```

Por lo que debes reemplazar o actualizarlo con esta sección:

```
exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATH = path.join('platforms', 'android', 'app', 'src', 'main', 'assets', 'www');
```

Comment: Por defecto tengo las dos configuraciones: 
`path.join('platforms', 'android', 'assets', 'www'),
path.join('platforms', 'android', 'app', 'src', 'main', 'assets', 'www')`.
He comentado la primera línea, para dejar unicamente la que me indicas, pero tampoco funciona. Me da el mismo problema. Eso sí, con el móvil Android sí que me funciona.

Comment: Hola, te funciona después de haber hecho la modificación a la linea o antes de ello te funcionaba tambien (plataformas Android)? Porque para pruebas nativas lo recomendable es que uses el sistema adecuado y así te evitas estos problemas, o sino puedes usar el sistema de Android Studio para realizar pruebas locales.

Comment: Ya me funcionaba antes de hacer la modificación. Por lo que parece es que en un navegador no llega a funcionar bien del todo...